# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Quiero tener el control de algunos TextBox de un formulario, habilitarlo o inhabilarlos desde valores establecidos en una Tabla, con el código siguiente:

```
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
   For Each Row As DataRow In dt.Rows     

       Dim NombreObjeto As String = String.Empty
       Dim Enabled As Boolean = Boolean.Parse(Row("MOSTRAR").ToString)
       NombreObjeto = Row("OBJETO").ToString

       Dim Ctrl As Control = FindControl(NombreObjeto)
       Dim Textbox As TextBox = DirectCast(Ctrl, TextBox)
       Textbox.Enabled = Enabled

   Next
End If
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in 
App_Web_h0j0jmch.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de 
un objeto.

Línea 462:                Dim Ctrl As Control = FindControl(NombreObjeto)
Línea 463:                Dim Textbox As TextBox = DirectCast(Ctrl, TextBox)
Línea 464:                Textbox.Enabled = Enabled
Línea 465:
Línea 466:            Next
```

Archivo de origen: Línea: 464

Saludos y Gracias por toda la ayuda que me puedan brindar

Comment: Haciendo debug qué valor obtienes en Ctrl?

Comment: me indica Nothing

Comment: Esa es la causa del error, debes validar si es diferente de nothing o null antes de declarar el textbox

Comment: Tienes que ver en debug el valor de `NombreObjeto` y luego ver si tienes un TextBox con ese nombre.

Comment: Roger tengo un Textbox con el nombre que obtengo de la tabla.

Comment: Eric, la validación es sobre el valor que obtengo de la tabla? porque si obtengo el valor que en este caso es el nombre del TextBox

Comment: Chequea que ese control que haces no lo realices antes de InitializeComponents() en el constructor.